# Problem about a multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Decide for which of the functions $F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ given below , there exists a function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ such that $(\nabla f)(x)=F(x)$.

(A) $(4xyz-z^2-3y^2,2x^2z-6xy+1,2x^2y-2xz-2)$.

(B) $(x,xy,xyz)$.

(C) $(1,1,1)$.

(D) $(xyz,yz,z)$.

We have , $(\nabla f)(x)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)$.

For (A) , if  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=4xyz-z^2-3y^2$ , $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2x^2z-6xy+1$ , $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2x^2y-2xz-2$ then , how I can say that the function $f$ exists or not ?

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$F = \nabla f$ for some $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ means that $F$ is a conservative field.

A vector function is a conservative field $\iff$ it has a $0$ [curl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)).

Comment: So option (A) and (C) are correct....Am I right? Please response..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: yes, only these are correct. Note that for part $(C)$ you can directly see that $f = (x,y,z)$ satisfies the requirement.